# Insert div above multiple divs with the same class in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Im trying to add a new div before every div that has the same class in a grid.

Right now my code only inserts the new div before the first div with the class **prod-grid** and I need to have the div inserted above all divs with the class **prod-grid**

Can anyone help me please?

```js
if (window.location.href.indexOf('/order/prod') !== -1) {
  var insertVirtualProductsPackInterval = setInterval(() => {
    if (document.getElementsByClassName('prod-grid')[0] !== undefined && document.getElementsByClassName('virtualProdSet-container').length === 0) {
      var virtualProdSetHTML = '<div id="newprod" class="virtualProdSet-container resp-outerBox" style="display: none;">' +
        '<div id="new-prod-banner" class="new-banner"></div>'+
        '</div>';
      document.getElementsByClassName('prod-grid')[0].insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', virtualProdSetHTML);
    }
  }, 100);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are only referring to the first `[0]` element rather than use a loop.

By the way, you have other issue with code, creating the `#new-prod-banner` element multiple times with same `id`. Good luck.

```js
if (window.location.href.indexOf('/order/prod') !== -1) {
  var insertVirtualProductsPackInterval = setInterval(() => {

    var prodGridElements = document.getElementsByClassName('prod-grid');
    for (var i = 0; i < prodGridElements.length; i++) {

      if (prodGridElements[i] !== undefined && document.getElementsByClassName('virtualProdSet-container').length === 0) {
        var virtualProdSetHTML = '<div id="newprod" class="virtualProdSet-container resp-outerBox" style="display: none;">' +
          '<div id="new-prod-banner" class="new-banner"></div>' +
          '</div>';
        prodGridElements[i].insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', virtualProdSetHTML);
      }
      
    }
  }, 100);

}
```

Comment: Hello! I tried this but it does not work. The div is displayed only on top of the first div with the class prod-grid.

Comment: yes this is because the condition `document.getElementsByClassName('virtualProdSet-container').length === 0` is being false after the first insertion.

Comment: I changed that to document.getElementsByClassName('virtualProductsPack-container').length >= 0 It still only inserts the div above the first div with class prod-grid...

Comment: can you set up a [mre] - (include relevant html)